# OracleDataAdapater.Fill() - Random NullReferenceException Exceptions

Tags: odp.net

I'm having an issue with OracleDataAdapater.Fill() method with random NULL reference exception (see the code & exception stack-trace below).  This happens a few times in a month in production environment and it is not consistently reproducible error in development.

I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.DLL (version 2.111.7.20 / Run-time version: v2.0.50727) in Visual Studio 2008 C# project and this code is hosted in IIS 7.0.

Is this a known issue in this version of ODP.NET that I'm using or something wrong with the coding below?

Please let me know.  Thanks!

Code:

```
OracleCommand objSelectCmd = new OracleCommand();

string sql = @"select * from TABLE_1 where MSG_ID = :msgId";

OracleParameter msgIdParam = new OracleParameter();
msgIdParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
msgIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
msgIdParam.Value = "ABC";
msgIdParam.ParameterName = ":msgId";
objSelectCmd.Parameters.Add(msgIdParam);

objSelectCmd.Connection = connection;
objSelectCmd.CommandText = sql;
objSelectCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataAdapter objAdaptor = new OracleDataAdapter(objSelectCmd);
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
objAdaptor.Fill(myDataTable);
```

I'm getting an exception OracleDataAdaper.Fill() method randomly.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader..ctor(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr[] opsSqlCtx, IntPtr opsDacCtx, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, OpoDacValCtx* pOpoDacValCtx, MetaData metaData, Int32 resultCount, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Hashtable safeMapping, String commandText, Int32 freeOpsSqlCtx)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
```

Comment: A few random suggestions: 1) Have the DBA check the alert log on the database side for the time of the crash. Perhaps there is a severed connection due to some server side issue that is being poorly handled by ODP.NET. An ORA error may show up in that alert log. 2) Get rid of the @ sign in front of the SQL string. It's not needed and is one more moving part to eliminate  3) Patch up ODP.NET if you can as there may well have been a bug. That is a very old version. Consider upgrading to ODP.NET 12.1 also.

Comment: Thank you Christian for your comments.  I will look into 1 & 3 and respond here.